# Invite New Collaborator Github API - Laravel PHP

Tags: php, laravel, github-api

Hey everyone I'm trying to **add a collaborator to my organisation** through the github api I am using Laravel I have the Graham\Github package installed with KnpLabs/php-github-api.

When I var_dump a already existing member I get an array just fine with the members status, but I cain't add members manually every time.

I would like to actually send an invitation to any github user to join the organisation as a member using the github api.

[Add or update organization membership](https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/members/#add-or-update-organization-membership)

[Add user as a collaborator](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/collaborators/#add-user-as-a-collaborator)
[image: Default role member for organisations]

[Add or update team membership](https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/teams/#add-or-update-team-membership)
[image: Default role member for teams]

If the user is unaffiliated with the team's organization, this endpoint will send an invitation to the user via email. This newly-created membership will be in the "pending" state until the user accepts the invitation, at which point the membership will transition to the "active" state and the user will be added as a member of the team. To add a membership between an unaffiliated user and a team, the authenticated user must be an organization owner.

All the functions I added in the library work with existing user but not found error when i try to invite what could be wrong  ?

```
public function createOrgMember($org, $username)
{
    return $this->get('/orgs/'.rawurlencode($org).'/memberships/'.rawurlencode($username));
}


public function addCollaborator($owner, $repo, $username)
{
    return $this->get('/repos/'.rawurlencode($owner).'/'.rawurlencode($repo).'/collaborators/'.rawurlencode($username));
}

public function createTeamMember($id, $username)
{
    return $this->get('/teams/'.rawurlencode($id).'/memberships/'.rawurlencode($username));
}
```

This works with existing user but doesn't invite a new user I get **error not found**

```
public function createMember()
{
  GitHub::connection('main')->organizations()->createOrgMember('retry24', 'project24retry');
}

array:6 [▼
 "url" => "https://api.github.com/orgs/retry24/memberships/project24retry"
 "state" => "active"
 "role" => "admin"
 "organization_url" => "https://api.github.com/orgs/retry24"
 "user" => array:17 [▶]
"organization" => array:11 [▶]
]
```

But this doesn't work

```
public function createMember()
{
  GitHub::connection('main')->organizations()->createOrgMember('retry24', 'david-dacruz');
}
```

This is the form

```
{{ Form::open(['route' => 'frontend.user.createMember',
'method' => 'PUT'
])}}

{{ Form::submit('Submit', ['type' => 'submit']) }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

The route

```
Route::put('dashboard/github', 'DashboardController@createMember')->name('createMember');
```

Thanks ahead!

Comment: On first link you posted, there are several cases when 404 is returned. Search for 404 on page and check if any of those fit your conditions.

Comment: Thanks I just checked **this** is the condition I'm in I want to invite a user to become an organisation member
                                                                                               **Response if requester is an organization member and user is not a member**
Status: 404 Not Found

There's a link back to the first link posted on this thread wich states : 

If the authenticated user is adding a member to the organization, the invited user will receive an email inviting them to the organization but I get error not found how can we work the magic here ?

Comment: I have tried many different methods all ending up the same if the user is already a member it's fine but i cain't get the invitation to through an api call to invite a new member to the organisation or to a team repo.

I'm really out of ressources on how to add this feature to my project any suggestions is greatly appreciated

Comment: I didn't see you passed parameter `role`.

Comment: That' s because it's indicated in the documentation that the default role is member and that's all I need is to invite new members. Thanks for feedback @Tpojka

Comment: Maybe to try only with php-github-api without Laravel porting to check result in that case?

Comment: Even though it is not my requirement I am curious on how to pass that parameter when I send the put request, what to add in the url ? I like the idea of your test case I'm going at it right away thanks alot !

Comment: I would go first with `?role=member`.

Comment: When i add `?role=member`, I get the same as before, what's actually really weird is that all the functions work when its already an existing member so I don't have any authentification problems the github app works ...

    `public function createOrgMember($org, $username)
    {
        return $this->get('/orgs/'.rawurlencode($org).'/memberships/'.rawurlencode($username).'?role=member');
    }`

Comment: @Tpojka thanks alot for your feedback, I managed to solve this because I created a smaller project to test this case wich helped me focus on the actual library and I could see my mistakes, thanks for you' re time this has been a valuable learning experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem I was trying to code a library function wich already existed.

Organizations.php class

```
 use Github\Api\Organization\Members;

 public function members()
{
    return new Members($this->client);
}
```

In this class the methods I wanted to create already exist:

Members.php

```
namespace Github\Api\Organization;

public function add($organization, $username)
{
    return $this->put('orgs/'.rawurlencode($organization).'/memberships/'.rawurlencode($username));
}
```

Then you can invite a member just like that the invitation will be pending and the user will get a mail to join the organization, once he or she has accepted to join , the status of the member will go from pending to active.

```
GitHub::connection('other')->organizations()->members()->add($organization, $username);
```